# Datatables returning formatted json data with javascript functions

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

Using Datatables with a .json source file, I am trying to manipulate the data before it shows in the table. I'm trying to simply remove spaces and replace with a dash in this example.

There are two ways I understand to do some data manipulation. One is columnDefs the other is using dataSrc and return the data. Both fail when i try to utilize .split or .replace or even .toLowerCase()...

For example, I have columnDefs added like so:

```
 columnDefs: [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                  console.log(data);
                  var cn = data.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
                  return cn;
                },
                "targets": 1
            }
        ],
```

The console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.split is not a function
```

How do we manipulate the data with replace or the like?

My data looks like:

```
{
    "Licensee": "Whistles for Woods",
    "Contact Name": "Bob",
    "Street": "2230 Trail",
    "Suite / PO Box": 0,
    "City": "Alturas",
    "ST": "CA",
    "Zip Code": 997733,
    "Telephone": 0,
    "Email Address": "bobc@email.com",
    "Website Address": "www.domain.com",
    "Fax": "No fax",
    "Products": "whistle with custom logo",
    "Categories": "Miscellaneous"
  },
```

Comment: How is your data formatted? If the data value is not a string or an array than it wont have the functions you mentioned. You will likely have to perform more in depth data manipulation to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen thanks for the comment. I added it in there. It is a string.

Comment: ah... you made me think there! Trying console.log(typeof data) told me most of the items are string, however, there was a number in there... I made data.toString() and now I'm able to manipulate it... I didn't think that would be necessary, however, this is a good check for sure since this isn't clean data always...

Comment: Nice! I was just about to suggest that lol. In that case I would just make an if statement like `if(typeof data === 'string'){ //do split and join }` and continue on with my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments

We just want to make sure that we are indeed manipulating strings and not any other data type. So in this case we would change the code to look something like this:

```
 columnDefs: [
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
              if(typeof data === 'string'){ 
                  //only if string manipulate
                  data = data.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
              }
              // OR data = data.toString(); whichever is more convenient!
              return data;
            },
            "targets": 1
        }
    ],
```